# Creating a random sample with the sum of the elements lower than 100

Tags: python, random

I want to create a random sample of 20 numbers with the constraint that the sum of the numbers must be between 0 and 100

I know how to create the random sample - how can I set my constraints?

```
import random

#Generate 5 random numbers between 10 and 100 for a list of 20 elements
randomlist = random.sample(range(0, 100), 20)
print(sum(randomlist))
```

Comment: What kind of distribution do you want to pull from? Do they have to be integers? This feels to me like there's a math/stats question that needs to be answered first before finding an appropriate coding implementation.

Comment: is it x in [0,100] or x in (0,100] or x in [0,100) or x in (0,100) that you want?

Answer (score 0):

Generate 20 random numbers, each random number is less than 5：

```
import random

randomlist = [random.uniform(0, 5) for _ in range(20)]
print(randomlist)
print(sum(randomlist))
```

Answer (score 0):

Conditional randomness - we append random data within the limits set by already chosen random data:

```
import random

randomlist = []
while len(randomlist) < 20:
    if len(randomlist)==0:
        s=0
    else:
        s=sum(randomlist)
    randomlist.append(random.randint(0, 100-s))
    
print(randomlist)
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the most straightforward ways to generate `k` random values that sum to a specific `total` is to:

- create a list consisting of the values 0, `total`, and `k-1` random numbers in the range (0,...,`total`);
- sort the list; and
- find the differences between successive pairs in the sorted list.

in Python:

```python
import random
import sys

def fixed_total(quantity, total):
    if total < 1:
        sys.exit('Error - non-positive total given as argument')
    cumulative_sum = [0, total] + [random.randint(0, total) for _ in range(quantity-1)]
    cumulative_sum.sort()
    return [cumulative_sum[i] - cumulative_sum[i-1] for i in range(1, len(cumulative_sum))]
```

Note that this approach will work with floats as well as with integers, if that's of interest.

To get a constrained random sum, all you need to do now is to generate the argument `total` as a random value subject to the constraint:

```python
def random_total(quantity, max_total):
    return fixed_total(quantity, random.randint(1, max_total))
```

If you want a non-uniform distribution on the constraint, just replace `random.randint` with any other distribution of your choice.

---

If you want to kick it up a notch, you could also have a lower bound on the values being summed.  After checking ranges for validity, reduce the `total` by `k * lower_bound`. Then add `lower_bound` to each of the values defined by the successive pair differences:

```python
def fixed_total_lower_bound(quantity, total, lower_bound = 0):
    if lower_bound < 0:
        sys.exit('Error: negative value given for argument low')
    total -= quantity * lower_bound
    if total < 1:
        sys.exit('Error: sum of lows ≥ total')
    cumulative_sum = [0, total] + [random.randint(0, total) for _ in range(quantity-1)]
    cumulative_sum.sort()
    return [cumulative_sum[i] - cumulative_sum[i-1] + lower_bound for i in range(1, len(cumulative_sum))]
```

As before, you can specify a constraint for the total, but will need to adjust it downwards by the `k * lower_bound`:

```python
def random_total_upper_bound(quantity, max_total, lower_bound = 0):
    total = random.randint(1, max_total - quantity * lower_bound)
    return [x + lower_bound for x in fixed_total_lower_bound(quantity, total)]
```

---

These four variants, invoked with:

```python
n = 5
max = 100

result = fixed_total(n, total = max)
print("fixed_total:", result, ": sum =", sum(result))

result = random_total(n, max_total = max)
print("random_total:", result, ": max =", max, "sum =", sum(result))

lo = 2
max = 15

result = fixed_total_lower_bound(n, total = max, lower_bound = lo)
print("fixed_total_lower_bound:", result, ": min =", lo, "max =", max, "sum =", sum(result))

max = 20

result = random_total_upper_bound(n, max_total = max, lower_bound = lo)
print("random_total_upper_bound:", result, ": min =", lo, "max =", max, "sum =", sum(result))
```

produce results such as:

```text
fixed_total: [41, 11, 6, 27, 15] : sum = 100
random_total: [0, 19, 4, 17, 1] : max = 100 sum = 41
fixed_total_lower_bound: [3, 2, 4, 3, 3] : min = 2 max = 15 sum = 15
random_total_upper_bound: [2, 3, 6, 2, 3] : min = 2 max = 20 sum = 16
```